# Handling errors in the Flows

Tags: visual-workflow, exception, visual-flows

I have a simple flow which just updates the record. But when updating the record, if it fails the users were getting an unhandled error exception. Like below:

`An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow  An unhandled fault has occurred while processing  the flow. Please contact your system administrator  for more information.`

So I tried to add a fault path in the flow which gives the users more meaningful error messages. The flow is like below on the Update Record if it fails I am placing a Screen which shows the fault message
[image]

The issue is I am getting a big error message

[image]

Is there a way we can extract the text from `{!$Flow.FaultMessage}` so that we can only show the error instead of the error code and all.

Comment: You could attempt to create a formula but to let you know upfront, it will prove extreme difficulty and more than likely will not work for all exceptions. You can customise your Error Screen component to include a hardcoded friendly message and have a System Admin capture a log file.

Comment: I've used the formula approach to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

What I try to do is the following: I create all branches that I can think of using decision elements in the use case logic and I direct these to an error screen that I write based on the condition. I use fault lines only for cases I cannot think of, because they also generate fault emails. I am to eliminate all cases that end up in fault lines.

So in your case, if the update is failing the chances are the record does not exist. I will get the record to see if there is one first and if it does not exist, I will show a screen explaining that.